# Mysql split records into two rows

Tags: mysql

I am selecting records from tables using the following query:

```
SELECT (@curRank := IF(@prevVal=stu_code, @curRank, @curRank+1)) AS 'index_no', 'ac01' as accNo, ""  as debitamount, amount as creditamount,   
@prevVal:=stu_code 
FROM payment p,(SELECT @curRank :=0, @prevVal:=null) r 

SELECT (@curRank := IF(@prevVal=stu_code, @curRank, @curRank+1)) AS 'index_no', 'ac02' as accNo, amount  as debitamount, "" as creditamount,   
@prevVal:=stu_code 
FROM payment p,(SELECT @curRank :=0, @prevVal:=null) r
```

As you can see, the only difference is the query is the `accNo`, and the `debitamount` and `creditamount`. But I cannot select in different query, it is not accurate. So how can I split one record into two rows with same index_no, but different `accNo`, `debitamount` and `creditamount`?

I guess it is more accurate to split one record into two rows.

Thanks.

Comment: You can use `UNION` syntax for that.

Comment: But is Union is function the same as two different query? And is it accurate for the data consistency? I am afraid that same index_no will be generated for different records.

Comment: sorry. I guess Union is good.

Comment: There is no difference in the two queries to differentiate debitamout and creditamount in your where clause. So using UNION will be best because you are manually assigning debit and credit amount

Comment: What is index_no suppose to be? If you need an unique identifier use the primary key + the type. If you need a "row number" you can just remove the initialization of `@curRank` and `@ prevVal` from the 2-nd part of the union.